# Java - conditional access to methods of a class

Tags: java

I am having to java classes `track` and `Session`.

The track class...

```
    package trackmanagement;

public class track {

    private String trackName, networkingEventTime;
    private Session morningSession, afternoonSession;

    track(String name)
    {
        trackName = name;
    }

    public void alloteSession()
    {
        morningSession = new Session("Morning Session", trackName);
        afternoonSession = new Session("Afternoon Session", trackName);
    }
}
```

The Session class...

```
    package trackmanagement;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Session {

    private String sessionName, relatedTrack, startTime, endTime;
    private ArrayList<Slot> allotedSlots;

    public Session(String name, String track) 
    {
        sessionName = name;
        relatedTrack = track;
    }

    public void morningSlots()
    {

    }

    public String afternoonSlots()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

In the method `alloteSession` in class `track`, I am making two objects of class `Session` with names `morningsession` and `afternoonsession`.

The class `Session` contains two methods namely `morningSlots` and `afternoonSlots`.

I want only `morningSlots` method to be accessed from `morningsession` object while `afternoonSlots` is private for `morningsession` object.

Similarly, `afternoonSlots` method should be accessed from `afternoonsession` object while `morningSlots` is private for `afternoonsession` object.

Thus there should be a conditional privacy for the methods. The method `morningSlots` should be public for `morningsession` object while it should be private for `afternoonsession` object and vice-versa.

Is it possible to do this, if not please suggest some other way to implement this kind of design.

Comment: No, there's nothing like that in Java. I suggest you just have a single method (`slots()`) or similar, and let each session know which slots are available. That gets you out of this design problem, and is generally much more flexible than a rigid "morning or afternoon" structure.

Comment: Instead of going for the above complex logic you can simply bifurcate the session logic in session class which will be responsible for the seesion depending upon the time like morninig or after noon.

like  Track magnt --> getSession-->Get session will check the time and will return the session accordingly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the method visibility from one class or another, you could create 2 classes `morningSession` & `afternoonSession` which would extend `session`.
`session` could be an abstract class with the method `slots()` which would need to be implemented in `morningSession` & `afternoonSession`.
From the implementation point of view when you create `session`s it is either `morningSession` or `afternoonSession` but in both case you can call the `slots()` method which will invoke the correct method

Answer (score 1):

You should change your design instead of trying something that's not possible in Java :)

```
    public abstract class Session {
       public abstract String getSlots();{//try to have methods that describes a verb/action
    }


    public class MorningSession extends Session{
       public abstract String getSlots(){
        return "Morning slot received";
       }
    }

    public class AfternoonSession extends Session{
       public abstract String getSlots(){
         return "Afternoon slot received";
       }
    }
```

By doing this, you wrap the implementation and let your Child Classes Morning/AfternoonSession to get the required slots.